# Laravel Redirect::back()->withErrors() not working in Test

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, integration-testing, functional-testing

Okay I'm having real trouble writing a functional test for a "incorrect credentials" login i.e. missing password.

For background here is my route configuration:

```
Route::get('login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'SessionController@create'));
Route::resource('session', 'SessionController');
```

Here is the content in my SessionController::store() method:

```
public function store()
{

    $credentials = Input::only('email', 'password');

    try {
        $this->loginForm->validate($credentials);

        if (!Auth::attempt(array('email' => $credentials['email'], 'password' => $credentials['password']))) {
            return Redirect::back()->exceptInput('password')->with('flash_message', 'Invalid credentials');
        }

        return Redirect::to('/')->with('flash_message', 'Welcome back');

    }
    catch (FormValidationException $e)
    {
        return Redirect::back()->exceptInput('password')->withErrors($e->getErrors());
    }

}
```

The above store() controller works perfectly in the browser(!) when I submit a form with POST action to /session. A form validation error is thrown and I get redirected back to /login with the $errors variable in my view correctly populated with the relevant message ("The password field is required"):

```
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    {{ $error }}
@endforeach
```

However when trying to replicate the expected working behaviour above in a functional test I have a problem. Here is the basic outline of my test:

```
public function testIncorrectCredentialsLogin()
{
    $this->client->request('GET', '/login');

    $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());

    $credentials = array(
        'email' => 'me@example.com',
        'password' => ''
    );

    $this->client->request('POST', '/session', $credentials);

    $this->assertRedirectedTo('login', array('errors'));

    $crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();

    $this->assertSessionHasErrors();

    $this->assertHasOldInput();

    $this->assertViewHas('errors'); // Fails

}
```

In my functional test I try to replicate what happens successfully in the browser. I first GET /login and then make a /POST to SessionController::store() with missing credentials which results in a validation error and a redirect back to /login. All okay so far but when I follow this redirect back I look within the rendered login page content/HTML and I have no $errors variable set and thus no messages available in the session/displayed in the page.

Can anyone advise what might be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a pro at functional testing but my guess is you may try to find your error HTML code in the HTML using the crawler object and not $this. When you do :

> $crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();

Means to me that now the crawler has the generated HTML by the redirection.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks elfif. I've already tried your suggestion with the following (the error messages display in an alert-box div):

    $this->assertCount(1, $crawler->filter("div.alert-box"));

This returns false (the alert-box is not in the content). If I simply $this->client->getResponse()->getContent() there is also no error message displayed. It's like the errors flash session is removed before I can view it?

Comment: The content can't be removed using the crawler because javascript is not interpreted by the crawler AFAIK. It's either the content is present from the beginning or it's not.

Answer (score 1):

in controller:

```
return back()->withErrors('name' => 'name is required!');
```

in blade(view):

```
<input
        type="text"
        id="name"
        class="form-control dt-uname @error('name') is-invalid @enderror"
        placeholder=""
        aria-label="jdoe1"
        aria-describedby="basic-icon-default-uname2"
        name="name"
        value="{{ old('name') }}"

/>
@error('name')
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
@enderror
```

Answer (score 0):

`withErrors` has to be an array

This **works** for me in the unit testing because it's an array `[]`.

```
return redirect()->route('projects')->withErrors(['Something went wrong']);
```

But this is **NOT** working.

```
return redirect()->route('projects')->withErrors('error', 'Something went wrong');
```